# npx react-native run-android does not launch app stays in IDLE

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I have been trying to learn react-native. On day one of initial setup, I was able to run the application on my android phone using following.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-android
```

On day two, I resumed working, but now the app would not launch or refresh. I had the app installed in phone from previous day. When I do `npx react-native run-android` I see following output.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no- 
jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 970 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app
Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [4m 49s]
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
:app:installDebug
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
```

I am trying to run following versions.

`react-native : 0.62.2`

On Android oneplus 7 physical device.
I have tried following.
`npx react-native start --reset-cache`
`adb kill-server`
`adb start-server`
`./gradlew build`